# Including distant relations when no direct relation is available (direct relation fields mapped as null)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

### Background

I'm creating a e-commerce'ish product catalog API where you can create categories, create products and assign them to categories.

As an additional feature it has attributes: when creating a category you can create attributes that are keywords that can be used to describe product properties. Under categories, you create the key and when creating a product for a category, the attributes can be given values.

For example

```
Category: "Tires"
Attributes: ["Manufacturer", "Dimensions", "FuelEconomyClassification", "WetGripClassification"]

Product: "Goodyear EfficientGrip"
Attributes: [
  "Manufacturer" => "Goodyear",
  "Dimensions" => "225/50/17",
  "FuelEconomyClassification" => "D",
  "WetGripClassification" => "B"
]
```

I also made a very minimalistic relations image to describe how it all comes together:
[image: Table relations]

### Laravel implementation

**Version:** 6.1

I've mapped all the tables as very simple hasMany/belongsTo relationships

```
Category
attributes() => hasMany(CategoryAttribute)
products() => hasMany(Product)

Product
attributes() => hasMany(ProductAttribute)
category() => belongsTo(Category)

CategoryAttribute
category() => belongsTo(Category)

ProductAttribute
categoryAttribute() => belongsTo(CategoryAttribute)
product() => belongsTo(Product)
```

I'm also using [Eloquent API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources) to make my API data servable and formatted.

### The Problem

A normal relation where I want to get a Products attributes is `Product->ProductAttribute[]`. This in most cases works perfectly. However, the issue comes up when at some point there is need to add a new CategoryAttribute to a Category.

My goal is to be able to see all attributes on a Products detail page, even if a value is not assigned (ProductAttribute).

Currently if I were to add a new CategoryAttribute and then I tried to view a Product, the newly added CategoryAttribute would not show up which is expected since there is no ProductAttribute relation in between.

So I'd like to able to somehow merge CategoryAttribute and ProductAttribute to one to be able to see all attributes and those, that don't have a ProductAttribute in the middle and map its values to null (like a left join), either directly through the relation or via the API Resource without causing an abundance of SQL queries to get executed.

My final attempt would probably be building a custom query for attributes and not a relation and serving that to my Resource but I'd like to leave that as a last resort and hear if someone has suggestions that might make the implementation less painful. If possible, I'd like to not break my Resources that I currently have in place.

Comment: I think you didn't relay the `CategoryAttribute` in your `Model list`.

Comment: @codeformoney I didn't add it to the question as I thought it wouldn't have any relevance but I added it now.

Answer (score 1):

It's little bit late, but may it can be helpful I hope.

I think it can be useful for you to present some good solution for your problem, as you said that you waiting for. Last times I had similar problem, and my teamlead introduced me some great pattern for this kind of situations. I'll try to explain as easy as possible. So here's the thing:

For first let's say we have 3 necessary tables: 'categories', 'attributes', 'products'. With these 3 tables we can build some normal structure for our system. With that we can have product, which can have multiple attributes, which belongs to some category. That's good. In this case, if admin will change some attribute (name of attribute or something like that), it will affect for all products, which has that attribute. But what if admin want to change some property of attribute only for specific product? We'll stuck on this.
Here comes 4th table: 'attribute_templates'. Here in that new table we'll store all attributes instead of 'attributes' table as before. But in 'attributes' table we'll store attributes with assignment their specific product. In this case admin can change some property value of attribute for specific product, and it will not affect to other products. Also any attribute can have different type, and it should belongs to some specific category. For example: phone (that's a category) product (Galaxy S9) can have some attributes like 'bluetooth', which will have boolean type (have / doesn't have), or 'back camera', which will have smallInteger type (7MP, 10MP, 12MP, etc). So each attribute will have their type (in 'attribute_templates' table) and value (in 'attributes' table). In case of when admin want to add/delete some new attributes, the system should add/delete that attributes only to/from 'attribute_templates' table. And in queries we'll use only 'attributes' table (nothing to do with templates table).
This pattern is good also when you want to add the new functionality to the DB. For example in one of my project I had apartments instead of products. Their had attributes, also amenities as well. For that I created also the 'amenity_templates' and 'amenities' tables, and connected that to the 'apartments' and 'categories' (like I did for 'attribute_templates' and 'attributes' table).

Here I'll attach an image as example of my pattern, which will show appropriate DB structure of that 4 tables via diagram (sorry for bad painting).

[image]

If you want, you can create and run some seeds for these tables with this sequence:

> 1. create categories
> 2. create initial attributes in the 'attribute_templates' (in this case 'attributes' table is still empty)
> 3. create product. if product must have for example 3 attributes, then it will copy that three records from 'attribute_templates' and import to the 'attributes' table, and assign them all to that product with ther attribute value appropriately.

Below I'll write the codes of Migrations (with right sequence) for each model.

**2019_05_19_100000_create_categories_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // PRIMARY
            $table->tinyIncrements('id');
            // ADDITIONAL
            $table->string('name', 250);
            // TIME
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

**2019_05_19_200000_create_attribute_templates_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAttributeTemplatesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('attribute_templates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // PRIMARY
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // FOREIGN
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade');
            // ADDITIONAL
            $table->string('name', 250);
            $table->string('value_type', 20)->nullable();
            // TIME
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('attribute_templates');
    }
}
```

**2019_05_19_300000_create_products_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // PRIMARY
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // FOREIGN
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade');
            // ADDITIONAL
            $table->string('title', 250);
            $table->string('image', 250)->nullable();
            // TIME
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

**2019_05_19_400000_create_attributes_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductAttributesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // PRIMARY
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // FOREIGN
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('template_id');
            $table->foreign('template_id')->references('id')->on('attribute_templates')->onUpdate('cascade');
            // ADDITIONAL
            $table->text('value')->nullable();
            // TIME
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_attributes');
    }
}
```

Below I'll write the codes of Models (with right sequence).

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        // PRIMARY
        'id', // tinyIncrements
        // ADDITIONAL
        'name', // string 250
    ];

    // RELATIONS
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
    public function productAttributeTemplates() {
        $this->hasMany(ProductAttributeTemplate::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**AttributeTemplate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AttributeTemplate extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'attribute_templates';

    protected $fillable = [
        // PRIMARY
        'id', // bigIncrements
        // FOREIGN
        'category_id', // unsignedTinyInteger nullable
        // ADDITIONAL
        'name', // string 250
        'value_type', // string 20 nullable
    ];

    // RELATIONS
    public function attribute(){
        return $this->hasOne(ProductAttribute::class, 'template_id');
    }
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = [
        // PRIMARY
        'id', // bigIncrements
        // FOREIGN
        'category_id', // unsignedTinyInteger
        // ADDITIONAL
        'title', // string 250
        'image', // string 250 nullable
    ];

    // RELATIONS
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
    public function attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**Attribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_attributes';

    protected $fillable = [
        // PRIMARY
        'id', // bigIncrements
        // FOREIGN
        'product_id', // unsignedBigInteger
        'template_id', // unsignedBigInteger
        // ADDITIONAL
        'value', // text
    ];

    // RELATIONS
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
    public function template(){
        return $this->belongsTo(AttributeTemplate::class, 'template_id');
    }
}
```

Now let's say, we want to add some phone product (OnePlus 7T), which will have following attributes: OS (OxygenOS 10), bluetooth (true), headphones (Type-C).

> 1. If there is not exists 'phone' product, we need do create that in 'categories' table.
> 2. Create new product 'OnePlus 7T' in 'products' table and assign that to 'categories' table.
> 3. Copy 'OS', 'bluetooth', 'headphones' attributes from 'attribute_templates' table, paste them to 'attributes' table and assign them to 'categories' table and 'products' table (to the appropriate 'phone' category and 'OnePlus 7T' product). And also if you need, you can write 'value' of attributes for each template. For us it will be: "OxygenOS 10" for OS, "true" for bluetooth, "Type-C" for headphones.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I read through your very thorough answer. Thank-you very much for that. But if I understood correctly (correct me if I'm wrong and I missed a sentence about it) this approach would have the same issue where I would create a new attribute to attribute_template for a category and it has existing products, those products would not get that attribute. My idea was to somehow have those attributes show up as well, but with null values.